# Missing date when i use dot

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When i use this code with dot i dont get anything...its blank but when i replace it with slash it works. Can someone tell me what is problem with this?

```
  @{
     String date = Model.Edit.BirthDate.ToString("dd'.'MM'.'yyyy.");
  }
   @Html.Label(date)


    @{
       String date = Model.Edit.BirthDate.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy.");
     }
     @Html.Label(date)
```

If i use this below i get only year because i didnt put dot at the end of year

```
@{
      String date = Model.Edit.BirthDate.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
 }
  @Html.Label(date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters (forward slash, and dot) are not special and can just be input as you want them displayed.

For example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") // 22.04.2015
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") // 22/04/2015
```

In fact, I think the problem is because you are using the wrong overload for `Html.Label`. The parameter you are supplying is supposed to be an expression that defines which property (from Model) to use. If you want to just display a text value (and not link it to a property) then just use:

```
@{
    String date = Model.Edit.BirthDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
}
@date
```

or if you want to render an html label:

```
<label>@(date)</label>
```

Comment: still nothing...i get just year because there is no dot there

Comment: @None: I have just tested both my examples and they work as expected. Did you actually try the code I suggested? Maybe some part of your `Model.Edit.BirthDate` path is null or not what it should be?

Comment: i did but like i say nothing happend.. i get just year

Comment: Try it with `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`, do you get the current date output?